# How to import CSV from frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I want to import my CSV. How to import CSV?

My CSV have three column **SKU,Product name,Qty** When i m import CSV that time i want to update product quantity and Stock Availability. I want to just update product quantity.How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to write a small script this script can be run without module or with module for import export from front end.If you run this script from root then you need to call magento function from outside.

Comment: Can you give me example?